# Formulating a problem in terms of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here is one problem I was trying to solve just by trial-and-error method. However, I was thinking about how to write the clear solution using set theory.

> **Problem:** A notebook contains exactly $100$ following statements, which of them is correct.
>
> (1) The notebook contains at least $1$ false statement.
>
> (2) The notebook contains at least $2$ false statements.
>
> $\vdots$
>
> (100) The notebook contains at least $100$ false statements.

Thus, if (100) is true, then so is (99), ..., (1). This means all statements are true. But then meaning of (100) contradicts this. Thus, (100) *must be* false.

Similarly, (99), (98), $\cdots$ (51) must be false.

After this, I didn't proceed further. Then I thought that it would have been better to express the hypothesis in terms of set theory, and just play with whether an element belongs to a set or not.

*How can we formulate this question in set theory? It may be easier, but I was already confused with arguments above.*

Comment: Russell's paradox shows that unrestricted set comprehension leads to a contradiction. As a corollary, there is no set of all sets. The theorem that every set (empty or not) has strictly smaller cardinality than its power set is Cantor's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem. I'm not sure either of them relate to your question, which looks like a variant of the Liar paradox. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox

Comment: Thanks for comment; I have removed the unnecessary part, and compressed the question a litte precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set theory is not at all necessary to make an argument rigorous. In many cases it even makes the notation more clumsy and obscure. Here is a reasonably formal proof that doesn't use any set-theoretic notation at all.

Given any integer $k$ from $1$ to $100$:

If the $k$-th statement is true:

Every statement before the $k$-th statement is true as well.

Thus there are at most $100-k$ false statements.

But by definition of the $k$-th statement there are at least $k$ false statements.

Thus $k \le 100-k$ and hence $k \le 50$.

Therefore the last $50$ statements are false.

Thus there are at least $50$ false statements.

Thus the first $50$ statements are true.

Amazingly, if you change the question to have an **odd** number of statements (say 101 instead of 100) then there is no solution!

Comment: I believe the OP explicitly makes your first note

Comment: @AndresMejia: No; the asker explicitly **rejects** my first note, and I disagree with that rejection, along with most native English speakers.

Comment: @user21820: This was a question in a Mathematics Paper, so I was   trying to take *precise* meaning of each statement. My solution to the problem is (51, 52, ... false); not much can be said.

Comment: @pGroups: Oh okay I get it; it's your own question you came up with. It seemed at first that you were asking about a problem you saw somewhere. I'll change my answer.

Comment: @AndresMejia: I misinterpreted the question to be about a problem seen somewhere. I've now fixed my answer.